# Get name / id of a OpenAI Gym environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Given:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
```

How do I get `CartPole-v0` in a way that works across any Gym env?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unwrap the environment and get the id from the spec

```
name = env.unwrapped.spec.id

print(name)
# 'CartPole-v0'
```

In vectorized environments, access the first sub-environment:

```
name = env.envs[0].unwrapped.spec.id
```

Comment: I don't think you need `.unwrapped`.

Comment: doesn't work for procgen `gym.make('procgen:procgen-heist-v0'); print(env.spec.id)` (which was added in 2020)